# How can I find the bitmap assignment of a png file? for RGB values

Tags: python, bitmap, png, variable-assignment

I have written the code below in Python:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("art.png")
width, height = img.size


Rs = [[""for j in range (0, width)] for i in range (0, height)]
Gs = [["" for j in range (0, width)] for i in range (0, height)]
Bs = [["" for j in range (0, width)] for i in range (0, height)]

for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        red, green, blue = img.getpixel((x,y))
        rb = "{0:04b}".format( int (red / 16))
        gb = "{0:04b}".format( int (green / 16))
        bb = "{0:04b}".format( int (blue / 16))
        Rs[y][x] = rb
        Gs[y][x] = gb
        Bs[y][x] = bb


print(Rs)
print(Gs)
print(Bs)
```

However, it gives an error saying:
line 20, in 
red, green, blue = img.getpixel((x,y))

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

How can I fix this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Currently you are just showing code that doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely are trying to open a png image with an alpha channel.
In that case

`red, green, blue, alpha = img.getpixel((x,y))`

should work.
I was able to reproduce the `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)` with a png with added alpha channel.